# thymeleaf: Retain selected value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf, dropdown

I am creating a simple webpage for report generation using springboot + thymeleaf. I have 2 dropdown values one dependent on another. I have tried selecting value in dropdown and upon selection, i have onchange event that calls JavaScript to get the values for the selected dropdown. While it does that, the selected value is not retaining in the dropdown, it get reset to default option.

I tried ways suggested in forums but none are easy for me to understand.

I have provided my code snippet below, please educate me what can i do to get my value retained in the first dropdown..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}"/>
    <link href="../static/css/start-test-view.css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/start-test-view.css}"/>
</head>

<script>
        function retrieveAppName() {
            if (history.pushState) {
              var selectedLOB = document.getElementById('lob').value;
              var _url = location.href;
              var newurl = ( _url.indexOf('lob') !== -1 ) ? _url : _url+'lob?lob='+selectedLOB;
              window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
              location.reload();
            }
        }
</script>

<body>
<div align="center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar-logo">
                <img alt="Dashboard" th:src="@{/img/logo.svg}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <header>
        <div class="navbar-primary">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <span class="portal">Report Summary</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-secondary"></div>
    </header>

    <div align="Left">
        <div class="container main-content">
            <div class="row card">
                <form class="form" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${dashboardParams}" method="post">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-container">
                        <label class="input-label">Line Of Business</label>
                        <select  th:name="lob" class="input-field" id="lob" name="lob" onchange="retrieveAppName()">
                            <option value="0">--select LOB--</option>
                            <option value="1">ALL</option>
                            <option th:each="lob:${listLOB}"
                                    th:value="${lob.line_of_business}"
                                    th:text="${lob.line_of_business}"></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-container">
                        <label class="input-label">Application Name</label>
                        <select class="input-field" id="appName" name="Application Name">
                            <option value="0">--select Name--</option>
                            <option value="1">ALL</option>
                            <option th:each="app:${listAppName}"
                                    th:value="${app.app_Name}"
                                    th:text="${app.app_Name}"></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-container">
                        <label class="input-label">Start Date</label>
                        <input class="input-field" type="date" id="sDate" name="Start Date"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-container">
                        <label class="input-label">End Date</label>
                        <input class="input-field" type="date" id="eDate" name="End Date"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <button name="Generate Report" class="submit" type="submit">Generate Report</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br/><br/>

    <div class="table">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
            <thead class ="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th>Application ID</th>
                    <th>Application Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>TestCase Path</th>
                    <th>Environment</th>
                    <th>Execution Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="runs : ${listRuns}">
                <td th:text="${runs.app_ID}">Application ID</td>
                <td th:text="${runs.app_Name}">Application Name</td>
                <td th:text="${runs.status}">Status</td>
                <td th:text="${runs.testcasepath}">TestCase Path</td>
                <td th:text="${runs.environment}">Environment</td>
                <td th:text="${runs.execdate}">Execution Date</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Controller Code:

```
@GetMapping("/lob")
public ModelAndView viewLOB(Model model, @RequestParam(value="lob", required=false) String lob) {
    List<AppData> lobName = dao.listLOB();
    List<AppData> appName = dao.listAppName(lob);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("listLOB", lobName);
    modelAndView.addObject("listAppName",appName);
    model.addAttribute("lastselected", lobName);
    modelAndView.setViewName("dashboardParams");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: You shoud add variable lob to your model, e.g. ..addObject(selectedLob, lob); and then add attribute th:selected="${selectedLob == lob.line_of_business}" to your option-element that starts with <option th:each="lob:${listLOB}" ...

Comment: Thanks much Flocke. It worked as you said. Thanks a lot for educating me here.